# nginx: worker process is shutting down

Tags: nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy, nginx-config, nginx-plus

[image]

[image]

What would be the reason for this nginx process not being killed for many days, I guess this is causing a lot of memory usage.

Note: I am using nginx and nginx tcp load balancing.